# convert hard coded Word bibliography list

Tags: microsoft-word

I have quite big word document ~250 pages. 
Word References/Citations not used.
References made in document are simple text:

> Tarptautinės savižudybių prevencijos asociacijos (angl. International Association for Suicide Prevention (IASP) rekomendacijas [18, 36, 202]. Tyrimais nustatyta, jog geresni specialistų savižudybių intervencijos įgūdžiai susiję su specifiniais savižudybių mokymais arba tiesioginiu specialistų darbu su savižudiškais pacientais [19, 176, 177].`

Bibliography list is entered by hand at the end of document.

> 1. Abbas M.A.F, Abu Zaid LZ, Hussaein M. Anxiety and Depression among Nursing Staff at King Fahad Medical City, Kingdom of Saudi Arabia. AIMS Medical Science 2015; 2(4): 303–309.
> 2. Ahmed-Little Y.Implications of shift work for junior doctors. BMJ 2007; 334:777–778.
> 3. Ahola K, Honkonen T, Pirkola S, Isometsa E, Kalimo R, Nykyri E et al. Alcohol dependence in relation to burnout among the Finnish working population // The Authors. Journal compilation. Society for the Study of Addiction 2006;11:1438 – 1443.
> 4. Ajzen I. Nature and Operation Attitudes. Annual Review of Psychology 2001;52:27–58.
>
> ...
>
> 250.

Is there a way except going one by one entry, to create proper bibliography list?

Comment: There could be. One could write a _Microsoft_ _Windows_ _Visual Basic for Applications_ Macro. However, I do not see it as a Trivial Issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up writing VB script

```
Sub ChangeText()


    Dim cDoc As Word.Document
    Dim cRng As Word.Range
    Set cDoc = ActiveDocument
    Set cRng = cDoc.Content
    cRng.Find.ClearFormatting

    'Dim dic As Dictionary
    'Set dic = New Dictionary

    Dim c As Object
    Set c = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    c.Add "x1", "1"
    c.Add "x2", "62"
    c.Add "x3", "2"

With cRng.Find
    .Forward = True
    .Text = "["
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Execute
    Do While .Found

        cRng.Collapse Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd
        cRng.MoveEndUntil Cset:="]", Count:=Word.wdForward

        Dim TextStr As String
        Dim Result() As String
        TextStr = cRng.FormattedText.Text
        Result() = Split(TextStr, ",")
        For i = LBound(Result()) To UBound(Result())
                Dim temp As String
                temp = CStr(LTrim(Result(i)))
                Result(i) = c(temp)
        Next i
        Debug.Print "before: " & cRng.FormattedText.Text

        cRng.FormattedText.Text = Join(Result, ", ")
        Debug.Print "after:" & cRng.FormattedText.Text
        cRng.Collapse Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd
        .Execute
    Loop
End With        
End Sub
```